# Metadata Label Registry

Tags: metadata, transaction-metadata

Is there an official "label registry" for (transaction) metadata?

[CIP 10](https://cips.cardano.org/cip/CIP-10) proposed such a registry, but I can not find it implemented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of reorganization on the CIP website and for whatever reason a number of links seem to have been broken.

The registry as I understand it is this chunk of JSON in the CIP GitHub, permalinked below for convenience.

- https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/868ae58447c953cc6115b61064af6d5ad30edd87/CIP-0010/registry.json

My understanding is that new labels are added via pull-request to this repo.